# c++ documentation in an R package

Tags: c++, r, namespaces, export

my R package uses Rcpp and RcppArmadillo. I built it in Rstudio.
I am following H.Wickhams guide (R-packages). The package builds (with one warning, see below), installs and runs fine.

cpp scripts have been documented using the  //' headers

I have several questions that i think are all related:

1. If i add `//'@export` to a cpp file then an entry of `export()` is added to `NAMESPACE`. Shouldn't it be export(filename)?
2. The `RcppExports.R` file contains a NULL value and during build i get a warning *"Warning: `RcppExports.R:18`: Missing name"*. Why is this? How do i rectify it?
3. How do i read the help file for the cpp script. ?filename doesn't seem to work like it does for R files in the package?

EDIT: snippet of code from  .cpp

```
//' @export
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat myfunc(int nSize, ... ,arma::cube suitability) { 
   do some stuff
}
```

Code from RcppExports.R (This NULL is the warning mentioned above)

```
#' @export
NULL
myfunc <- function(nSize, ..., suitability) {
   .Call('_myfunc', PACKAGE = 'mypackage', nSize, ... , suitability)
}
```

and code from RccpExports.cpp

```
// Generated by using Rcpp::compileAttributes() -> do not edit by hand
// Generator token: 10BE3573-1514-4C36-9D1C-5A225CD40393
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// myfunc
arma::mat myfunc(int nSize, ..., arma::cube suitability);
RcppExport SEXP _myfunc(SEXP nSizeSEXP, SEXP suitabilitySEXP) {
BEGIN_RCPP
  Rcpp::RObject rcpp_result_gen;
  Rcpp::RNGScope rcpp_rngScope_gen;
  Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< int >::type nSize(nSizeSEXP);
  Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< arma::cube >::type suitability(suitabilitySEXP);
  rcpp_result_gen = Rcpp::wrap(myfunc(nSize, ..., suitability));
  return rcpp_result_gen;
END_RCPP
}

static const R_CallMethodDef CallEntries[] = {
    {"_myfunc", (DL_FUNC) &_myfunc, 9},
   {NULL, NULL, 0}
};

RcppExport void R_init_mypackage(DllInfo *dll) {
   R_registerRoutines(dll, NULL, CallEntries, NULL, NULL);
   R_useDynamicSymbols(dll, FALSE);
}
```

**SOLUTION**: Thanks to Anders and Ralf

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
//' calculates stuff
//'
//' Calculates the stuff
//'
//'@param nSize number of some stuff
//'@param p2
//'@param p3
//'@param p4
//'@param p5
//'@param p6
//'@param p7
//'@param p8
//'@param suitability 3D array 
//' @export
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat myfunc(int nSize, ... ,arma::cube suitability) { 
  do some stuff
}
```

Comment: Have you included a `// [[Rcpp::export]]` line as well in each Rcpp roxygen block?

Comment: "cpp scripts" - C++ is *not* a scripting language. C++ source files are *not* scripts.

Comment: @hrbmstr yes. i have `// [[Rcpp::export]]` directly above the function. But i have `// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]`
`#include <RcppArmadillo.h>` in between `//'@export` and `//[[Rcpp::export]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have something like

```
//' @export
// [[Rcpp::export]]
```

*right* before your function definition. The first is Roxygen saying that the function is to be exposed to the user-interface. The second line is telling Rcpp to export to the R-side---i.e. the functions are simply put/exported into `RcppExports.Rcpp` and `RcppExports.R`. Two different things where the former only makes sense if the latter is provided too.

The Roxygen comments `\\'` are just carried on to the `RcppExports.R` file.

**Edit:**
From your comments, I see you metion RcppArmadillo. You only need to `#include <RcppArmadillo.h>` once at the top of your `.cpp` file. The `// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]` is not needed.

Comment: thanks, i read this in Hadley Wickhams book (p99) but this creates an error.  "Evaluation error: C:/Users/.../R/RcppExports.R:18:1: unexpected [[". It places `[[` right before the `Rcpp::depends` function call. And like i mentioned. Everything runs fine so there isn't a problem of the code not exporting

Comment: @andy I have edited my post. If that does not work, could you provide some snippets of the src code, the code in RcppExports.Rcpp and RcppExports.R in your post?

Comment: @andy The include should only be once at the top of the document. The NULL comes because the `\\' @export` is not 'attached' to the function definition.

Comment: Thanks. I think i get what you are saying. I placed the `#include <RcppArmadillo.h>` on the very first line of the file. Then followed by the `//'` statements in one contiguous block (including the `//'@export`). This was the solution. I now don't have NULL and i can read help file. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

The `roxygen` comment has to be next to the function(s) it applies to. Different combination of such comments are possible:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

//' @export
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat myfunc(int nSize, ... ,arma::cube suitability) { 
   do some stuff
}

//' @export
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat myotherfunc(int nSize, ... ,arma::cube suitability) { 
   do some other stuff
}

// C++ internal function, i.e. usable in the packages C++ code
arma::mat cppinternal(int nSize, ... ,arma::cube suitability) { 
   do some other stuff
}

// R internal function, i.e. usable in the packages R code 
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat Rinternal(int nSize, ... ,arma::cube suitability) { 
   do some other stuff
}
```